# Jquery UI Dialog box close event all possible way into one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Close event of dialog box(using the close button) in jquery can be handled by

```
close: function(e, ui) {
        // do your thing...
}
```

I also tried `closeOnEscape: false,` but this option fails for me. I don't know why(I have 2 dialog box in one context) since one dialog doesn't close on escape the other one closes. Then there is another way to close the dialog using the X button.

> I am wondering is there an event that handles all ways on closing jQuery UI dialog box all in one?

UPDATE

I am not looking for a way to close dialog that triggers an event that is all together. I want to know the event that will trigger close so that I can do a function on close of dialog

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
$('.selector').dialog('close');
```

for example: (suppose id of dialog is 'my-dialog')

```
$("#my-dialog").dialog("close");
```

If you want to close same dialog you have opened, you can use ***this***:

```
$(this).dialog('close');
```

Comment: write i dont understand this kind of answer can you elaborate

Comment: i am not looking for a way to close because I have given 3 ways to close in my OP I want to know the event that will trigger close so that I can do a function on close of dialog

Comment: Suppose you have anchor tag on cross icon, you can fire also click event on this. Otherwise on Close() method you can write the same

Comment: If you have a separate button to close the dialog, write this one line inside the method and call that method once you trigger the button. There is a lot of option :)

Answer (score 1):

check JQuery official site, here you will get all info:  you can get a lot of same type of questions with Answers on StackOverflow (already asked)!
 https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close

Code examples from JQuery website:
Initialize the dialog with the close callback specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  close: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref : [Close event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close)

```
$('.dialog').dialog({
close: function(e, ui) {
    // do your thing...
 }
});
```

to close all dialog boxes at once try

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

since all dialog boxes are inherit from the class `.ui-dialog-content`

> It will get fired even if the dialog is not open so try to use this in dialog close method(above)